# General Linear Systems

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if the following systems are compatible and, if so, find the general solution:
$2x_1-6x_2+4x_3=2$ and
$-x_1+3x_2-2x_3=-1$

How can I set this system into a matrix to determine if they are compatible and then how can I determine its general solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, put your two equations into a matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
       2 & -6 & 4 & 2           \\[0.3em]
       -1 & 3 & -2 & -1            \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix} $\\$
Next, you want to put your matrix into reduced row echelon form:
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & -3 & 2 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0            \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix} $\\$
Now, you can write your general solution as: $\\$

$x_{1}$ = 1 + 3$x_{2}$ - 2$x_{3}$ $\\$

$x_{2}, x_{3}$ are your free variables since those columns do not contain any pivots. $\\$

Where: $\\$

$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 + 3x_{2} - 2x_{3}\\
        x_{2}\\
        x_{3}\\
        \end{pmatrix} | x_{2},x_{3} \in\ S\\$